# If an object's key's value is an array, it will generate a new object

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to ensure that you get the desired output, such as using `lodash`

I want to pass a method to generate my mongoose query conditions.

```js
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

/* expected
newObj = {
  $and: [
    {
      age: 22
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {sex: 1},
        {sex: 2},
      ],
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {name: {first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}},
        {name: {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}}
      ],
    },
  ]
}


*/
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Of course, but always not expected

Comment: not good enough bro.. you should share your code to help us *guide* you.. rather than building it instead of you

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the hint, but my code is really bad, I worry that it will cause you to make wrong judgments

Comment: Kindly approve the answer you found helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Plain JavaScript

You don't strictly need Lodash to do it. Here is how you can achieve this with plain JavaScript. The code is slightly more verbose for descriptive purposes:

```js
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

/*
 * take a key-value pair where the value is an array
 * and turn it into an array where each object 
 * is a key-value pair. For example:
 * `["age", [22]]` into [{age: 22}]
 * `["sex", [1, 2]]` into `[{sex: 1}, {sex: 2}]`
 */
const toFilterObjects = ([key, values]) => values.map(value => ({[key]: value}));

/*
 * combine objects into an OR relationship 
 * or a single one into just equality. For example:
 * `[{age: 22}]` into `{age: 22}`
 * `[{sex: 1}, {sex: 2}]` into `{'$or': [{sex: 1}, {sex: 2}]}` 
 */
const combineOr = arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  
  return {
    '$or': arr
  }
}

/*
 * combine objects into an AND relationship 
 * or a single one into just equality. For example:
 * `[{age: 22}]` into `{age: 22}`
 * `[{sex: 1}, {sex: 2}]` into `{'$and': [{sex: 1}, {sex: 2}]}` 
 */
const combineAnd = arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  
  return {
    '$and': arr
  }
}

//manipulate all values of the object to turn them into OR filters
const temp = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(toFilterObjects)
  .map(combineOr);

//AND all filters
const result = combineAnd(temp);
  
console.log(result);
```

The biggest improvement to this code is that `combineOr` and `combineAnd` can actually be generalised in a single `combine` operation and you can derive the two from it. This will reduce the code duplication:

```js
const combine = key => arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  
  return {
    [key]: arr
  }
}

const combineOr =  combine('$or');
const combineAnd = combine('$and');
```

In addition, the `temp` variable is generally unneeded but wanted to make the separation between the operations within the array and the operation on the whole array.

## Normal Lodash

Lodash *can* help here. It's not reducing the operations to a single function call but it can help clean up some of the extra cruft and produce slightly better looking code slightly easier than using vanilla JavaScript functionality by using [chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash):

```js
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

const toFilterObjects = ([key, values]) => values.map(value => ({[key]: value}) );

const combine = key => arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  
  return {
    [key]: arr
  }
}
  
const result = _(obj)
  .entries()
  .map(toFilterObjects)
  .map(combine('$or'))
  .thru(combine('$and'));
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## Lodash FP

Lodash also has [a functional programming build](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) that allows structuring the code using more functional approach. If already using functional style in the project, Lodash FP is preferable to plain Lodash but even without having a predominantly functional code, this is an alternative:

```js
const { entries, map, flow } = _;

let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

const toFilterObjects = ([key, values]) => values.map(value => ({[key]: value}) );

const combine = key => arr => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];
  
  return {
    [key]: arr
  }
}

const process = flow(
  entries,
  map(toFilterObjects),
  map(combine('$or')),
  combine('$and')
)

const result = process(obj)
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

Comment: Great, I am very excited to see this answer, this is the answer I am looking forward to. I really admire your superb technology, thank you very much for your answer, I will adopt your answer, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you mean correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```js
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

let output = { $and: [] };

for (let prop in obj) {
  if (obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
    if (obj[prop].length === 1) {
      output.$and.push({ [prop]: obj[prop][0] })
    } else {
      let $or = [];

      for (let item of obj[prop]) {
        $or.push({ [prop]: item });
      }

      output.$and.push({ $or: $or });    
    }
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{first: "Wang", last: "Hao"}, {first: "Tang", last: "Jie"}]
}

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accumulator, key)=> {
   let elem = {}
   if (Array.isArray(obj[key])){
     if (obj[key].length > 1) {
       elem['$or'] = obj[key].map(item => ({[key]: item}))
     } else {
       elem[key] = obj[key][0]
     }
   } else {
      elem[key] = obj[key]
   }
 
   accumulator['$and'].push(elem)
   
   return accumulator
}, {'$and': []})

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
  age: [22],
  sex: [1, 2],
  name: [{ first: "Wang", last: "Hao" }, { first: "Tang", last: "Jie" }]
}

function generateQuery(obj) {
  let andQuery = [];
  for (let key in obj) {
    let value = obj[key];
    if (value.length === 1)
      andQuery.push({ [key]: value[0] });
      else {
        let orQuery = value.map(v => {
        return { [key]: v };
      });

      andQuery.push({ "$or": orQuery });
   }
}
return { "$and": andQuery }
}

generateQuery(obj);
```